# Proportional scaling to max width and height with ImageCache

Tags: 6, media

I am not sure if this really is this difficult, or if I can't come up with the right search terms, but an [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) use case has me stumped right now.

I have a theme where I need to proportionally scale images to a max height and width (ie, a bounding box), and if possible center the image on a colored background.

For example, lets say I have a 1024x768 image and max size is 500x400.  I need ImageCache to make a 500x375 image.  The action would need to work for arbitrary image sizes, as the input varies widely.

Non-proportional scaling and/or cropping is not an option due to usage rights.

What is the best option here?  I have gone through module that add additional ImageCache actions, but did not see any that did this.  I suspect I could use [ImageMagick Raw Effect](http://drupal.org/project/im_raw) but I would rather not rely on a particular toolkit, as I may need a portable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two scale actions to a preset.  On the first one, set the width to 500, and in the second, set the height to 400.  Since they don't by default up-scale, that should bound you in your box.